# Android/Java Javadoc missing after updating Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

After i recently installed the new Android SDK stuff, I no longer can view the Javadoc while editing my project's code.  I get this message: `Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.`

I am getting this message for all methods, variables, classes, etc.

I have installed the documentation and everything available to me via the android update manager.  I have also tried to do a clean install of the android sdk and eclipse, and no luck getting the javadoc working.

I have also tried manually setting the javadoc via `project properties -> javadoc location -> file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk-windows/docs/reference/` with no luck

What suggestions do you have that could fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this problem.  All i had to do was delete the `.metadata` folder in my workspace, and restart eclipse.  note: this will clear all your eclipse preferences, settings, etc.  your workspace projects will need to be added again.

also consider the following link as it seems to be very helpful for most people viewing this: http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2011/02/losing-javadocs-in-eclipse-solution.html

Comment: This solved my same problem except that that now I cannot browse inside any folders even after restarting!!  Something broke :(.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11753052/q.png.  Any suggestions ??

Comment: Oops.!! my perspective was 'Java Browsing' instead of 'Java'. Everything is all right now :)

Answer (score 23):

Deleting .metadata is not a good solution because you'll lose all of your settings. I poked at this a bit and was able to figure it out. Full writeup is here:

http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2011/02/losing-javadocs-in-eclipse-solution.html

Answer (score 7):

```
1) In eclipse, right click on your Android project and select Properties
2) On the menu on the left, select "Java Build Path"
3) On the right hand side, select the "tab" labelled "Libraries".
4) Here you should see the Android SDK that you're targeting. For example: "Android 2.2".
5) Click on the arrow to the left of the Android SDK to expand the sublevels.
6) Find "Android.jar" and click on the arrow to the left of that one as well to expand it.
7) You'll see a setting called "Javadoc location". Select that and then click on the     "Edit" button.
8) At the top, RESELECT the path to your javadocs. This is usually "path_to_android_sdk/android-sdk-mac_86/docs/reference/". I say RESELECT because even if it's right, you should browse and do it over anyway.
9) Click on "validate". You should be all set now!
```

Answer (score 2):

One more suggestion: With my installtion, changing the path did not work! Validating was ok, but after closing the project properties, it switched back to the old wrong path. (After installing the Android SDK, I moved it to another location; the wrong javadoc path was to that old location before moving. This probably caused my problem.)

My solution now was: Opening the Eclipse preferences, go to Android, and there change the SDK Location path by "Browse" to the new location. I did type in the new location, but after browsing to it, the d:... changed to D:... -- and magically, after this, I could now change the javadoc path in the project settings and it remembers my choice. Even building new Projects now works like expected with the correct javadoc path right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was that I couldn't see javadoc also for other libraries though path's validating was ok.

Unfortunately solution of cjserio didn't help. I didn't want take binnyb's solution.

According to answer from Jockel I looked at Android SDK location and saw that the path was "C:\Progra~1\Android\android-sdk" instead of "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk".

Though it's correct way but after relocation I'v got "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" as the location path and could see all javadocs again also after restart of Eclipse

**UPD**
But then I get the next problem. I couldn't start simulator anymore because plugin couldn't understand path anymore. This issue was caused by space in "Program Files".

But i've [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter/6684981#6684981) for this problem as well

Working fine for me