# How to use Android documentation while developing in Eclipse with ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, documentation, javadoc, adt

I have installed Documentation for Android package using AVD manager.
On hovering over any element it pops up "*Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc*"

I can't figure exactly what needs to be set in javadoc location in project properties or something else needs to be done :-/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451330/android-java-javadoc-missing-after-updating-android-sdk didn't help?

Comment: Oh sry for repeating the questrion !!   This solved my same problem except that that now I cannot browse inside any folders even after restarting!! Something broke :(. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11753052/q.png. Any suggestions ??

Comment: try to ask a new question (after checking for duplicates) for your new problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android/Java Javadoc missing after updating Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451330/android-java-javadoc-missing-after-updating-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, try running Project > Clean in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any example on where the javadoc isn't available? I had the same doubts, but as soon as I opened the Eclipse view "Javadoc" and selected the class/method I wanted to know more about, there the doc appeared.