# The Android emulator is not starting, showing "invalid command-line parameter"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I made a simple "Hello World" program in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I added nothing to a Java file and only added a text view in file `main.xml` as

```
//main.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And now when I run my program it shows the following in the console.

```
//console output
[2011-07-10 07:10:22 - demo] ------------------------------
[2011-07-10 07:10:22 - demo] Android Launch!
[2011-07-10 07:10:24 - demo] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-10 07:10:24 - demo] Performing com.demo.DemoActivity activity launch
[2011-07-10 07:10:25 - demo] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'vishal'
[2011-07-10 07:10:25 - demo] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'vishal'
[2011-07-10 07:11:06 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
[2011-07-10 07:11:07 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-10 07:11:07 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

This shows my [Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html) (AVD) could not start due to some reason. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: [Starting Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6603194/501771)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

- If your SDK location path in Eclipse is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\` change to `C:\PROGRA~2\`.
- If you are running 32-bit Windows, `C:\Program Files\`, change the path to `C:\PROGRA~1\`.

[image]

Answer (score 317):

There is currently a problem with R12 where the SDK location cannot contain any spaces.

The default installation location is: `C:\Programme Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk`. They are currently fixing the problem but you can currently work around it by changing the SDK location path in eclipse to `C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk`.

If you are running 32-bit Windows, change the path to `C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk`.

Comment: If you don't know the 8-dot-3 name of your desired path, just fire up a Command Prompt and execute "DIR /X"... the short name will be displayed next to each directory.

Comment: Can this be fixed in Eclipse?

Comment: I've tried this and it's still not working on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine. My SDK is in the following path D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk and I've put the following in my SKD location path in eclipse but with no luck. D:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1

Comment: I ended up just copying the android-sdk directory directly into the root of the D drive adn updated the SDK path in Eclipse to reflect the new location. Worked like a charm.

Comment: that is ridiculous, I reckon 99% of people encounter this problem when attempting to get started with android!

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer I needed, NickC! However, I ran into similar problems with actually running the AVD; I just moved the whole android-sdk folder to "C:\Programs\Android\android-sdk" and changed my PATH, etc, and that solved my issues. (I set aside the '\Programs' folder for non-installed Win apps, like traditional Eclipse and various command line tools.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd just like to add that the directory path entry is case-sensitive so you must use 'PROGRA~1' literally when changing this value in Eclipse (Window->Preferences->Android) or whatever IDE you are using.

Answer (score 52):

I'd suggest creating a directory junction *named* `C:\Android` pointing to the actual `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\`:

```
MKLINK /J C:\Android "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\"
```

and then setting the newly created junction as SDK Location for your Eclipse ADT Plugin (Eclipse menu\ Window\ Preference\ Android).
This might help for a number of tools/ plugin too that have problems with spaces in paths.

Comment: Nice idea. You could also create it as a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link), which is the newer way since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 24):

NickC is correct. It is also worth pointing out that the SDK location is set in Eclipse > Window menu > Preferences > Android. If your folders are different you can check the 8.3 format of any folder with **dir *foldername* /x** at the command prompt.

Answer (score 15):

I had this issue as well. The solution is (if you are on Windows as I am) to change the path to `C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk-windows\`.

Assuming `Program Files` is the first directory with the word PROGRAM in it which it should be. This worked.

Answer (score 7):

I started Task Manager, made sure adb.exe is closed (it locks some files)

Create the folder C:\Android
Moved folder + all files from **C:\Program Files\android-sdk** to **C:\Android**

Edited ***C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Android SDK Tools*** shortcuts.

I considered uninstalling the SDK and re-installing, but for the life of me, *where does it store the temp files??*  I `don't` want to re-download the platforms, samples and doco that I have added to the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I made it work with:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator-arm.exe"  @foo
```

`foo` is the name of your virtual device.

Comment: likewise - how the heck did you do that phil??

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the PROGRA~2 method (which is not working for example in [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)), you can create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

It can be named, for example, `prg` to `Program Files` (run `mklink /?` from the command line to learn how to do it). Then run the emulator as `C:\prg\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe`. Also change the path to SDK/emulator in your [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: @Kev What about duplicate questions? :P

Answer (score 3):

emulator-arm.exe error, couldn't run.
Problem was that my laptop has 2 graphic cards and was selected only one (the performance one) from Nvidia 555M. 
By selecting the other graphic card from Nvidia mediu,(selected base Intel card) the emulator started!

Answer (score 2):

Remember to run "android update avd -n avd_name" after change in Android SDK path.

Answer (score -2):

This don't work since Andoid SDK R12 update.
I think is because SDK don't find the Java SDK Path.
You can solve that by adding the Java SDK Path in your PATH environment variable.