# Error Android SDK: invalid command-line parameter files

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

It won't start the virtual device. Why can't things just work??

I'd rather not reinstall everything outside Program Files directory and I don't know and don't care what Eclipse is.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter

Answer (score 10):

Its because of the spaces in "Program Files (x86)".
From the eclipse menu bar do this

1. Go to Window > Preferences
2. Click Android
3. At the "SDK Location bar" change it from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk** to **C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk**

It should work perfectly now. (However if you're using a 32bit system then you'd have to change it to 'Progra~1' not 2.)

Comment: I'm not using eclipse, what should I do? I get the same error

Comment: @CodingTales what IDE are you using?

Comment: @CodingTales no matter IDE you're using, changing the file path to the sdk to Progra~2 should still work.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you installed the SDK in a path with a space in it. Try uninstalling and installing to C:\Android or something.

Source: http://ideanotion.net/android-sdk-invalid-command-line-parameter-files-error/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows install:

1. Create an AVD with the *Android SDK and AVD Manager*, remember what AVD name you used.
2. Start Command Prompt, go to the SDK Tools folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`.
3. Type `emulator.exe -avd "avd_name`, (e.g. `emulator.exe -avd AVD_1.5`).