# unable to start emulator

Tags: android, tags

Recently I updated the ADT Plugins in eclipse and also installed the sdk package 3.0. After that, I couldn't able to start the emulator. I got the following error while starting emulator: invalid command-line parameter: Nino.. How can I resolve this?

Comment: view  recently solved that problem[1]

[cant-able-to-start-the-android-virtual-avd-device][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156463/cant-able-to-start-the-android-virtual-avd-device/7156528#7156528

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Android SDK: invalid command-line parameter files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920816/error-android-sdk-invalid-command-line-parameter-files)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you haven't installed the SDK in a folder with spaces in its name.
Spaces don't allow the SDK to run properly...

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried restarting the abd? This can be done inside the DDMS, and if you look in the devices panel (left upper corner) you'll see there is a little narrow pointing down next to the snapshot icon (a camera) and from there you can restart the abd. 
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem are the spaces in the path, so just from:

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk

to: C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk

If you have a 64 bit system

From: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk to:

C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk

Translated from: http://satoriwd.com/astath/?p=11

Comment: Thanks for all your valid answers. I solved the problem.I have uninstalled the android sdk and installed again. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

go to your system task manager-->processes-> you can see the adb running as (adb.exe) kill that process, and then start your avd.

Comment: There is no spaces in the parent path. Even i kill adb.exe in task manager and i try to start the emulator, but facing the same problem

Comment: when start emulator the adb will automatically run.