# android AVD emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error Android SDK: invalid command-line parameter files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920816/error-android-sdk-invalid-command-line-parameter-files)

I transfered my files to a new computer but now when I try to run the AVD through eclipse I get this error:

[2011-08-23 22:20:58 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-08-23 22:20:58 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-23 22:20:58 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

What is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

sdk path can't contain spaces.May be your sdk is in some path like c:/program files/...So a space in program files directory.Place it in a directory where there is no spaces in the path

Answer (score 0):

Try updating it using:

```
android update avd -n foo
```

Where `foo` is your AVD name.

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied the files to a path with spaces (E.g., C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/)
Try moving it to C:/Android (No spaces in the path).

If you want to maintain a path with spaces do something like this:

In Eclipse, Windows -> Preferences -> Android Tab -> SDK Location

> Change
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>
> to
>
> C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk

or

> C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
>
> to
>
> C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

At the command line:

```
mklink /J c:\Android "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

Next, you want to change the path to your Android SDK to point to C:\Android.