# Problem installing Android, invalid command-line parameter

Tags: android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Emulator is not starting showing " invalid command-line parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter)

I installed the SDK for android, but the Emulator will not start.

I attempt to start the Android Emulator but get this error.

invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information

As you can see from the error message; the file path has a Unix forward slash in it and I am running a windows system.

I need help fixing this problem and I have already tried reinstalling the SDK, which did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you vote that this post is not helpful then please explain why. I did not give very much information about the problem because I do not know anything more then what I have stated. A picture of the Emulator window would have helped, but I am new to stackoverflow so I can not post images.

Answer (score 0):

John is correct. I was having the same problem and error. I uninstalled the Android SDK and re-installed directly under my 'C' drive as 'C:\Android'. Once the install was complete, I ran the update for all possible packages. At that point I ran the emulator and it ran perfect.

Since I use Windows 7 64-bit, the default location for 32-bit applications is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'. The multiple spaces in the primary folder name was causing the trouble.

Just make sure, if you are using Eclipse, to go back into Eclipse and update the file path for the SDK or Eclipse won't work correctly.