# SDK manager close Error

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am having trouble using android sdk manager when it starts everything is fine but when i close it an error comes up

```
---------------------------
Android SDK Manager - Output
---------------------------
WARNING: Java not found in your path.    
Checking if it's installed in C:\Program Files\Java instead (64-bit).

Java was found at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe.    
Please consider adding it to your path:    
- Under Windows XP, open Control Panel / System / Advanced / Environment Variables    
- Under Windows Vista or Windows 7, open Control Panel / System / Advanced System Settings / Environment Variables    
At the end of the "Path" entry in "User variables", add the following:    
  ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe
```

and when i add path same error comes up every time.

I am new to this please help

I am running windows 7 64 bit

**UPDATE:**
Tried and Uninstall and install version 6 instead of 7 but did not solved my problem.

I donot know why

Answer (score 1):

You are using java 7..

I am sure android sdk does not fully support java 7 as oracle just released java 7.

Go for lower versions of  java like java 6 or jdk 1.6

Comment: No Use installed but no effect

Comment: Install jdk/java/android sdk to paths where there is no spaces or special characters...Please dont install sdks in  program files dir..

Comment: is there some issue regarding Public or Private Jre

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter