# invalid command-line parameter: Dev

Tags: android

I am new (very new) to android development. I followed some instruction to install and begin my first development.

When I run the project, i got this error, I cannot find a solution.

```
[2011-09-04 19:49:16 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Dev.
[2011-09-04 19:49:16 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-09-04 19:49:16 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Anyone pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined any virtual devices yet? Directly after installation there are none created for you. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html for more help on this subject. You can create your own configured devices and set it to the wanted api level.

Please also not the current problem with windows not be able to start any emulators when the latest android sdk is installed at the default program folder: [The Android emulator is not starting, showing "invalid command-line parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter)