# android eclipse emulator device not running

Tags: android, eclipse

i am new in android eclipse when i run the emulator it give that error i also remove the previous virtual device  and create a virtual device but it not run.here the error below,

```
invalid command-line parameter: course.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

and also give these errrors:

```
[2011-09-19 12:12:47 - androidinterface] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'fyp'
[2011-09-19 12:12:48 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: course.
[2011-09-19 12:12:48 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-09-19 12:12:48 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue and is annoying.

Go in to Eclipse and change th location of your Android SDK from `C:\Program Files\Android` to `C:\Progra~1\Android` if you're on Windows XP / Windows Vista 32 bit / Windows 7 32bit.

If you're on Windows Vista 64 bit or Windows 7 64 bit, this will be installed in the Program Files (x86) directory so change it to `C:\Progra~2\Android`.

More detailed instructions

- Open **Eclipse** and open your workspace
- With the workspace open go to **Window** > **Preferences**
- Click the **Android** section
- If you are on Windows XP / Vista / 7 32 bit, change the **SDK Location** to `C:\Progra~1\Android`
- If you are on Windows Vista / 7 64 bit, change the **SDK Location** to `C:\Progra~2\Android`
- Hit **Apply** then click **OK**

Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 1):

You got a space in your sdk path. Move it to a different path without one.

Alternatively you can change the path inside the eclipse preferences. Change it to `C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk` on a 64 bit system, or to `C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk` on a 32 bit one *(if you installed the SDK in the default location)*.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter) for more information.