# Unable to start an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-2.2-froyo

I've just installed Eclipse with fresh Android SDK and ADT on Windows 7 x64 Professional. I've created an emulator and tried to start it, but starting fails with this message:

```
invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

When I create another emulator, it also fails to start with the same message. Can anyone provide a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "Files" tells me there is a script somewhere that is running a binary in `"C:\Program Files"` but is bombing out because of the space in the name. You may want to try reinstalling the Android SDK/ADT somewhere other than under "Program Files" like say `"C:\AndroidSDK"` to see if this fixes it...

Comment: Also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476122/android-eclipse-emulator-device-not-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the path of Android SDK to make sure it has no spaces, for example use Progra~1 instead of Program Files.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works! I'm a bit confused, why the installer lets me install the SDK in such a directory..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a path that contains withespace for the SDK installation.
You can also try from command line:

```
emulator @foo
```

considering that your PATH includes the SDK installation directory.