# Mac Android Emulator not showing up

Tags: android, command, emulation

I have already found a solution for this problem on Windows but not for Mac. Here it is: [The Android emulator is not starting, showing "invalid command-line parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/the-android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter)

Emulator has worked before but now I am getting this strange error:

Log:

```
[2012-06-05 23:29:30 - Together Game Free] ------------------------------
[2012-06-05 23:29:30 - Together Game Free] Android Launch!
[2012-06-05 23:29:30 - Together Game Free] adb is running normally.
[2012-06-05 23:29:31 - Together Game Free] Performing com.motioncoding.togetherfree.TogetherGameActivity activity launch
[2012-06-05 23:29:31 - Together Game Free] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'API4'
[2012-06-05 23:29:31 - Together Game Free] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'API4'
[2012-06-05 23:29:31 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: emulator.
[2012-06-05 23:29:32 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2012-06-05 23:29:32 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled eclipse now it works again.