# Android Eclipse cannot find program "sh " in PATH

Tags: android, path, sh

I'm trying to run program using android ndk. Eclipse shows problem "Program "sh" not found in PATH C/C++ Problem". I've already made a reference to ndk folder in path. What is "sh"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on Windows. Setting the correct path for Android NDK in the Eclipse `Preferences->Android->NDK` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the project works fine after removing the project from the workspace and import again. I don't know why:(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with `NDK`, probably you have spaces defining the path of your sdk.

Check if you have specified the `NDK` path as

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-ndk
```

avoid the "spaces", so change to:

```
C:\Progra~1\Android\android-ndk
```

Read : [The Android emulator is not starting, showing "invalid command-line parameter"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638713/the-android-emulator-is-not-starting-showing-invalid-command-line-parameter) (applies for `SDK` & `NDK`)